# Javascript - Change variable on resize not working with JSSOR Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I'm trying to change var screenWidth; when resizing the window to mobile. It's working when I load it, but not when resizing. What am I missing here? I'm using the jssor slider. I can see in console that screenWidthFunction() is working.

js:

```
    var screenWidth;

    function screenWidthFunction() {

        if( $(window).innerWidth() < 768 ) {            
            screenWidth = 960;
            console.log(screenWidth);
        } else {
            screenWidth = 1920;
            console.log(screenWidth);
        }

    }

    //var screenWidth = 1920;

    screenWidthFunction();

    function ScaleSlider_home_1() {
        var refSize_home_1 = jssor_home_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        if (refSize_home_1) {
            refSize_home_1 = Math.min(refSize_home_1, screenWidth);
            jssor_home_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize_home_1);
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider_home_1, 30);
        }
    }
    ScaleSlider_home_1();

    $(window).bind('load',function(){
        //screenWidthFunction();
        ScaleSlider_home_1();
    });              

    $(window).bind('resize',function(){
        screenWidthFunction();
        ScaleSlider_home_1();
    });            

    $(window).bind('orientationchange',function(){
        //screenWidthFunction();
        ScaleSlider_home_1();
    });
```

That's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/df58scsk/1/

Comment: show your html and css

Comment: Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/df58scsk/1/

Comment: it resized with full width, do you mean fixed width if `< 768`

Comment: ähh ... little confused :-) ... well as you can see in the example if screen size is smaller than the breakpoint and you rerun it ... you get the full width ... but if you resize it over the breakpoint ... I don't automatically get the full width ... which I also would like to have. Hope my description is not too confusing ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    screenWidthFunction();
    ScaleSlider_home_1();
});
```

You don't need to bind event

Comment: Unfortunately no difference. JSSOR still  ignores the variable change for some reason ...

Comment: Please see here: jsfiddle.net/df58scsk/1

Comment: I check this fiddle you see in jquery is already change value of `screenWidth`, You have any other query?

Comment: Yes, at the end I want the slider to be also full with when < 768 ... just with the new geometrics. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You may need one of the examples below,

https://github.com/jssor/slider/blob/master/examples/full-window-contain-mode.html
https://github.com/jssor/slider/blob/master/examples/full-window-cover-mode.html

And we will publish version 25.3.0 in a few days, it comes with full-window-flex-mode.html which targets mobile device.